# Why compass module is affected by its x,y position, if my phone's compass work in the same environment?

Tags: sensor, electromagnetism, magnetics, shielding, compass

I am using hmc5883L on an autonomus robot. It shall remain in a 1 meter squared area. I have recently discovered that its reading changes up to 20 degrees on different positions even when it is facing the same direction (values are consistent within a given point though).

I believe there should be a magnetic field distribution in my room (a slight tilt might also exist for that matter). I am about to take this as a huge error percentage, however I really prefer not to. So I thought I may check if my phones (iphone) "compass" application will diverge 20 degrees as well. It didn't even diverge 1 degree.

So my question is, how is this even possible if such a magnetic distribution exists? Does phones use a different method to tell the position of north? Is there anything I could do to make my readings more consistent with changing positions?

Comment: Composs aren't 2d things. You seems to forget that there is a third axis. You should compute your X,Y values with the Z axis. My guess is that in order to provide a real 2d value, you'll need a gyroscope. As I understand the compass give you the "coordinate" of the magnetic field. But if you want to project it in 2d, you'll have to make a projection of the 3 vectors on the perpendicular vector from ground.

Comment: I preferred not to use gyroscope I had too much noise. I considered applying a kmer filter but I was afraid that the errors would accumulate on long run (I will be using it about 10-15 minutes straight). If I cannot find a way around, I will consider that again.

Comment: And could you elaborate about the third axis? How could z axis affect the measurement of x and y up to 20 degrees, and how can I compensate for it? (I just checked and z value indeed changes a lot, although compass face approximately upwards(so z should be same as well) )

Comment: Well, I believe it could be possible to achieve that without a gyroscope. If the device can be placed in a way that it can move freely, you could apply some kind of weight that will force it to be perpendicular.

Comment: Do you think it will have significant effect to make sure it is absolutely perpendicular? At the moment it is probably tilted about 1 maybe 2 degrees at most.

Comment: In fact, I just made it about 10-15 degrees to see if it will mess up everything, it didnt affect x,y axis. I still have about 20 degrees disruption. Thats why I think cause is probably something else.

Comment: Earth is a 3d sphere. The poles aren't exactly straight in front or back. So every axis contain information about the 2 others in theory. The combination of the 3 axis should give you the direction of the strongest magnetic field. So if you change the angle of your device and the X axis points to the floor, you'll see that the X axis will probably have a value close to what the Z axis has when it's in a normal position.

Comment: 1 or 2 degree might not change anything right, maybe there is something generating a magnetic field close to the sensor then.

Comment: If the 20 degree disruption is constant, you might have to calibrate it with your position on earth. Not sure if the iphone actually does that. As far as I remember, In Quebec there is a 15degree error on a compass.

Comment: It would not work because so many different points have quite different values. Error is like 0degree, 5degree, 3degree, 10 degree, 20degree, 15degree, 5 again etc. as device moves in a straight line facing the same direction.

Comment: Just had an interesting idea, how about I take a z reading as a reference and subtract the change in z reading from other two? Because if a gradient magnetic field of constant direction is causing this, its affect to each individual axis should be related in someway. And I know z axis always looks up so change in z value gives change in gradient strength. It is a long shot but the only one I could think so far.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say but a few things I'd try to do. If there is something in the room disrupting the sensor, you can easily find out. 1. When the device isn't moving are the results stable? 2. Move the device yourself in a straight line as gently as possible so the device doesn't shake at all. Are the reading stable? 3. If they aren't stable as you move accross the room. Can you repeat the same reading as you move in a straight line.

Comment: I was not able to find anything disrupting so far. 1- Results are always stable at a given point. 2- As I move the device slowly, reading change, however it always change the same (different regions have different values but same region always have a consistent value). 3- yes, I have the same reading at the same point of the line on different trials. but there are too many different points in a 1meter square region to create a lookup table.